# What do RNN neural networks lack in nowcasting time series?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, economics

I want to write a master thesis on nowcasting GDP? Has this been used and if so I don't fully understand how the neural networks should be built if I forecast quarterly GDP and link that to unemployment how would the neural network update my prediction for 1st quarter GDP when the Feb unemployment is released compared to using only the Jan one. I am now sure where the update element should be placed in an RNN architecture?